# Opening Ipython notebook from boot2docker in windows

Tags: windows-8.1, ipython, docker, jupyter-notebook, boot2docker

I am using a Surface Pro 3 with Windows Pro 8.1. I'm trying to access an IPython notebook from docker. The command I am using is

```
ipython notebook --no-browser --port 8888 "--ip=*"
```

The notebook is running but it is not opening in my browser, this is what I get when I run it

```
[I 23:16:44.921 NotebookApp]B Using existing profile dir: u'/home/itam/.ipython/profile_default'
[I 23:16:44.990 NotebookApp]B Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[C 23:16:45.012 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[C 23:16:45.012 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
[I 23:16:45.018 NotebookApp]B Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/itam/mate-computacional/itam-mate-computacional
[I 23:16:45.018 NotebookApp]B 0 active kernels
[I 23:16:45.018 NotebookApp]B The IPython Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/
[I 23:16:45.019 NotebookApp]B Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

The IP address of my virtual machine is 192.168.59.103, but `https://192.168.59.103:8888/` doesn't open the notebook.

Comment: I think you need to explicitly tell it to expose port 8888 from your VM as 8888 on your local system. See http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#container-port-redirection

Answer (score 1):

Start boot2docker and create new docker container **ipython1**:

```
docker run -it -ip 8888:8888 -v //c/Users/USERNAME://usr/data --name ipython1 <image_name>
```

**image_name** - name of your docker image

**-v** *folder_in_your_win_machine:folder_in_docker_container*

**-ip** *port_in_win:port_in_docker_container*

Start docker container **ipython1** and launch ipython notebook in docker container:

```
docker start ipython1
docker exec -it ipython1 ipython notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser
```

Next go to windows browser and enter url: *docker_ip*:8888.
To know docker IP execute:

```
boot2docker ip
```